# If no image, display text?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm having a problem finding a code that will display text (`<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>`) when no image has been defined in the img src= (`<?php echo get_option('to_logo'); ?>`).  This works in Firefox, of course, as a simple alt tag.  But doesn't cut it in all browsers.

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_option('to_logo'); ?>" title="Logo" alt="Logo" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler just to do something like:

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<?php
if (get_option('to_logo') != '') {
?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_option('to_logo'); ?>" title="Logo" alt="Logo" />
<?php
} else {
    echo bloginfo('name');
}
?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like WordPress.  You can try to first test the image source to see if it is empty:

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<?=(get_option('to_logo')) ? '<img src="'.get_option('to_logo').'" title="Logo" alt="Logo" />' : 'The alternate text'; ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (get_option('to_logo') == '') {
    echo bloginfo('name');
} else {
    echo get_option('to_logo');
}
```